# Specific Jquery Function Not Working on iOS devices only

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ios

My website is resizing text based on the container for the text previews on the signs, however when I try to use this on an iphone it is appearing horribly and not the correct sizes at all. Is there something specific about iOS that could cause the below function to look different?

You can see an example of it here: http://emilyc30.sg-host.com/product/all-stencil-cut-signs/

The code to resize (that breaks on iOS) is below:

```
function wpb_hook_javascript() {
    ?>
<script>
function resizeText() {
    var div = document.getElementsByClassName('apaou-text-layer');
    var input = document.getElementsByClassName('pewc-advanced-preview-field');
    
    div.innerText = input.value;

    resizeContents();
}

function resizeContents() {
    var resizableDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('apaou-text-layer');
    for (index = 0; index < resizableDivs.length; ++index) {
        var div = resizableDivs[index];
        if (div.innerText != '') {
            var divWidth = div.clientWidth;
            var divHeight = div.clientHeight;

            var contentWidth = div.scrollWidth;
            var contentHeight = div.scrollHeight;

            var fontSize = div.style.fontSize;
            fontSize = Number(fontSize.substring(0, fontSize.length - 2));

            while (contentWidth <= divWidth && contentHeight <= divHeight) {
                fontSize += 1;
                div.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'px';
                contentWidth = div.scrollWidth;
                contentHeight = div.scrollHeight;
            }

             while (contentWidth > divWidth || contentHeight > divHeight) {
                 fontSize -= 1;
                 div.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'px';
                 if (fontSize < 20){continue};
                 contentWidth = div.scrollWidth;
                 contentHeight = div.scrollHeight;
             }
        }
    }
}

</script>

    <?php
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'wpb_hook_javascript');
```

Code that doesn't quite work but doesn't break iOS is here:

```
function wpb_hook_javascript() {
    ?>
<script>
function resizeText() {
    var div = document.getElementsByClassName('apaou-text-layer');
    var input = document.getElementsByClassName('pewc-advanced-preview-field');
    
    div.innerText = input.value;

    resizeContents();
}

function resizeContents() {
    var resizableDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('apaou-text-layer');
    for (index = 0; index < resizableDivs.length; ++index) {
        var div = resizableDivs[index];
        if (div.innerText != '') {
            var divWidth = div.clientWidth;
            var divHeight = div.clientHeight;

            var contentWidth = div.scrollWidth;
            var contentHeight = div.scrollHeight;

            var fontSize = div.style.fontSize;
            fontSize = Number(fontSize.substring(0, fontSize.length - 2));
            
            while (contentWidth < divWidth || contentHeight < divHeight) {
                fontSize += 1;
                div.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'px';
                contentWidth = div.scrollWidth;
                contentHeight = div.scrollHeight;
            }
            
             while (contentWidth > divWidth || contentHeight > divHeight) {
                 fontSize -= 1;
                 div.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'px';
                 contentWidth = div.scrollWidth;
                 contentHeight = div.scrollHeight;
             }
        }
    }
}

</script>

    <?php
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'wpb_hook_javascript');
```

So the problem code is `while (contentWidth <= divWidth || contentHeight <= divHeight) {` causing iOS browsers to crash

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've narrowed down the specific cause of the issue on iOS but I don't know why it is a problem. I have updated the question to reflect my finding.